# How to modify string using RegEx?

Tags: ruby, regex

How do I transform the string from 'updown' to 'Up/Down' using RegEx?

Comment: `'updown'.gsub(/^.*$/, 'Up/Down')` =)

Comment: keruilin - you have to explain better how you expect to get that output, what other input strings might look like, and will you resolve ambiguous input. As it is, I doubt this question can be answered.

Answer (score 2):

If you already know the input and output string then there's no use case for regular expressions. Regular expressions are for matching a grammar, which is a set of strings, rather than a single string.

Are you looking for something more general? Perhaps your question is about how to split up the words up and down, or how to capitalize the letters?

Answer (score 1):

```
    string = "updown"
    string.gsub!("up", "Up!")
    string.gsub!("down", "Down")
string = "Up!Down"
```

Comment: I think `string = "Up!Down"` is enough in this case.

Comment: haha i know, but i'm just trying to help with gsubs!